# mysql: merge two records into one

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have the below result set from my query (which has a UNION of two SELECT queries)

```
app_id  transaction_id  mobile_no   user_input1                          user_input3                           user_input17                     user_input110                     user_input61            user_input62
104     731           918087318987  Welcome To Onida~Home Appliances    Home Appliances~Washing Machine Washing Machine~Fully Automatic Fully Automatic~SPARKLE 65S                NULL                  NULL
104     731           918087318987      NULL                               NULL                                     NULL                            NULL                           Quantity ~2                Amount~2
```

I want to merge these two records into 1 row

```
app_id  transaction_id  mobile_no   user_input1                          user_input3                           user_input17                     user_input110                     user_input61            user_input62
104     731           918087318987  Welcome To Onida~Home Appliances    Home Appliances~Washing Machine Washing Machine~Fully Automatic Fully Automatic~SPARKLE 65S           Quantity ~2                Amount~2
```

I can provide my SQL query but it is too long. Will provide if required.

**SQLSchema:**

```
create table `trn_user_log` (
`app_id` int (11),
`transaction_id` int (11),
`mobile_no` varchar (45),
`node_id` bigint (20),
`customer_attribute` varchar (150),
`entered_value` varchar (150)
); 

insert into `trn_user_log` (`app_id`, `transaction_id`, `mobile_no`, `node_id`, `customer_attribute`, `entered_value`) values('104','731','918087318987','103','Welcome To Onida','2');
insert into `trn_user_log` (`app_id`, `transaction_id`, `mobile_no`, `node_id`, `customer_attribute`, `entered_value`) values('104','731','918087318987','105','Home Appliances','1');
insert into `trn_user_log` (`app_id`, `transaction_id`, `mobile_no`, `node_id`, `customer_attribute`, `entered_value`) values('104','731','918087318987','119','Washing Machine','1');
insert into `trn_user_log` (`app_id`, `transaction_id`, `mobile_no`, `node_id`, `customer_attribute`, `entered_value`) values('104','731','918087318987','121','Fully Automatic','2');
insert into `trn_user_log` (`app_id`, `transaction_id`, `mobile_no`, `node_id`, `customer_attribute`, `entered_value`) values('104','731','918087318987','169','Quantity ','2');
insert into `trn_user_log` (`app_id`, `transaction_id`, `mobile_no`, `node_id`, `customer_attribute`, `entered_value`) values('104','731','918087318987','170','Amount','2');


create table `mst_node` (
`app_id` int (11),
`node_id` bigint (20),
`parent_node_id` bigint (20),
`display_seq` tinyint (4),
`display_text` varchar (540),
`customer_attribute` varchar (150)
);

insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','103',NULL,'1','Welcome To Onida','Welcome To Onida');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','105','103','2','Home Appliances','Home Appliances');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','119','105','1','Washing Machine','Washing Machine');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','121','119','1','Fully Automatic','Fully Automatic');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','124','121','2','SPARKLE 65S ','SPARKLE 65S ');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','125','121','3','Sparkle 65X','Sparkle 65X');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','126','121','4','Sparkle 62P','Sparkle 62P');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','169','124','1','Quantity ','Quantity ');
insert into `mst_node` (`app_id`, `node_id`, `parent_node_id`,  `display_seq`, `display_text`,  `customer_attribute`) values('104','170','124','2','Amount','Amount');
```

**My SQL Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT T1.app_id,
   T1.transaction_id,
   T1.mobile_no,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input1,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 105 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input3,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 119 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input17,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 121 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input110,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 169 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input61,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 170 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input62
FROM trn_user_log T1 INNER JOIN mst_node T2 ON T1.APP_ID = T2.APP_ID
 WHERE     T1.app_id = 104
   AND T1.transaction_id = 731
   AND T1.node_id = T2.parent_node_id
   AND T2.`display_seq` = T1.entered_value
--   GROUP BY T1.app_id, T1.transaction_id, T1.mobile_no
--  ORDER BY T1.node_id

UNION 

SELECT T3.app_id,
   T3.transaction_id,
   T3.mobile_no,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input1,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 105 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input3,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 119 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input17,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 121 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input110,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 169 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input61,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 170 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input62
FROM trn_user_log T3 INNER JOIN mst_node T4 ON T3.APP_ID = T4.APP_ID
WHERE  T3.app_id = 104
   AND T3.transaction_id = 731
   AND T3.node_id = T4.node_id
   AND  not exists (select 1 from mst_node b where b.parent_node_id = t4.node_id)

--        GROUP BY T3.app_id, T3.transaction_id, T3.mobile_no
-- ORDER BY T3.node_id
)T 
GROUP BY T.app_id, T.transaction_id, T.mobile_no
```

[SQLFiddle Demo Schema and Query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfcd8/1)

Comment: Is it always the case that one row will have data and the other will have NULL for the corresponding columns? If not, what should the combined row contain for those columns?

Comment: if you see the two select queries, the columns which will return Null in the first queries will have values in the second query and vice versa.. I want to merge these two records into one so ideally there will be no NULL values in the final result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `JOIN` two selects with each other and then perform `COALESCE` on columns.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfcd8/15

```
SELECT app_id,transaction_id,mobile_no,
coalesce(tt1.USER_INPUT1,tt2.USER_INPUT1) AS USER_INPUT1,
coalesce(tt1.USER_INPUT3,tt2.USER_INPUT3) AS USER_INPUT3,
coalesce(tt1.USER_INPUT17,tt2.USER_INPUT17) AS USER_INPUT17,
coalesce(tt1.USER_INPUT110,tt2.USER_INPUT110) AS USER_INPUT110,
coalesce(tt1.USER_INPUT61,tt2.USER_INPUT61) AS USER_INPUT61,
coalesce(tt1.USER_INPUT62,tt2.USER_INPUT62) AS USER_INPUT62
 FROM (SELECT T1.app_id,
       T1.transaction_id,
       T1.mobile_no,
       CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T1.node_id
                 WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input1,
          CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T1.node_id
                 WHEN 105 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input3,
          CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T1.node_id
                 WHEN 119 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input17,
          CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T1.node_id
                 WHEN 121 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input110,
       CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T1.node_id
                 WHEN 169 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input61,
       CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T1.node_id
                 WHEN 170 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input62
  FROM trn_user_log T1 INNER JOIN mst_node T2 ON T1.APP_ID = T2.APP_ID
 WHERE     T1.app_id = 104
       AND T1.transaction_id = 731
       AND T1.node_id = T2.parent_node_id
       AND T2.`display_seq` = T1.entered_value
--   GROUP BY T1.app_id, T1.transaction_id, T1.mobile_no
--  ORDER BY T1.node_id
) AS tt1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT T3.app_id,
       T3.transaction_id,
       T3.mobile_no,
       CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T3.node_id
                 WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input1,
          CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T3.node_id
                 WHEN 105 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input3,
          CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T3.node_id
                 WHEN 119 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input17,
          CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T3.node_id
                 WHEN 121 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input110,
       CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T3.node_id
                 WHEN 169 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input61,
       CONVERT(
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             (CASE T3.node_id
                 WHEN 170 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
                 ELSE NULL
              END)) USING LATIN1)
          AS user_input62
FROM trn_user_log T3 INNER JOIN mst_node T4 ON T3.APP_ID = T4.APP_ID
WHERE  T3.app_id = 104
       AND T3.transaction_id = 731
       AND T3.node_id = T4.node_id
       AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mst_node b WHERE b.parent_node_id = t4.node_id)

--        GROUP BY T3.app_id, T3.transaction_id, T3.mobile_no
-- ORDER BY T3.node_id
  ) AS tt2 USING (app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no)
```

Comment: Thanks.. this worked and more or less the thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you `union` and a `subquery` then join it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  -- place your unioned query 
) a
GROUP BY a.app_id, a.transaction_id, a.mobile_no
```

Comment: I tried this thing but I am getting one row same as the first record that I have mentioned above... that means last two columns (`user_input61` AND `user_input62`) are still NULL..

Comment: much better if you can add the schema and sample records. :D

Comment: hmm.. I know you will need that.. let me see i can squeeze it into some limited number of records..

Comment: I have created a schema and provided my query in SQLFiddle in the main question. Hope this helps you now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no,
       MAX(user_input1) user_input1, MAX(user_input3) user_input3,
       MAX(user_input17) user_input17, MAX(user_input110) user_input110,
       MAX(user_input61) user_input61, MAX(user_input62) user_input62
FROM (
SELECT T1.app_id,
   T1.transaction_id,
   T1.mobile_no,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input1,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 105 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input3,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 119 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input17,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 121 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input110,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 169 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input61,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T1.node_id
             WHEN 170 THEN CONCAT(T1.customer_attribute, '~', T2.display_text)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input62
FROM trn_user_log T1 INNER JOIN mst_node T2 ON T1.APP_ID = T2.APP_ID
 WHERE     T1.app_id = 104
   AND T1.transaction_id = 731
   AND T1.node_id = T2.parent_node_id
   AND T2.`display_seq` = T1.entered_value
--   GROUP BY T1.app_id, T1.transaction_id, T1.mobile_no
--  ORDER BY T1.node_id

UNION 

SELECT T3.app_id,
   T3.transaction_id,
   T3.mobile_no,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 103 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input1,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 105 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input3,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 119 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input17,
      CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 121 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input110,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 169 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input61,
   CONVERT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
         (CASE T3.node_id
             WHEN 170 THEN CONCAT(T3.customer_attribute, '~', T3.entered_value)
             ELSE NULL
          END)) USING LATIN1)
      AS user_input62
FROM trn_user_log T3 INNER JOIN mst_node T4 ON T3.APP_ID = T4.APP_ID
WHERE  T3.app_id = 104
   AND T3.transaction_id = 731
   AND T3.node_id = T4.node_id
   AND  not exists (select 1 from mst_node b where b.parent_node_id = t4.node_id)

--        GROUP BY T3.app_id, T3.transaction_id, T3.mobile_no
-- ORDER BY T3.node_id
)T 
GROUP BY T.app_id, T.transaction_id, T.mobile_no
```